# How to disable constructors in custom exceptions?

Tags: apex, exception, constructor, nooverride, custom-exception

There is a lot out there on how you can't override exception constructors and how to do custom exceptions, but I haven't been able to find anything on disabling a constructor for an extended class.

I've created a custom class that coworkers are (basically) using as the original Exception class.  As a counter measure, I wanted to override the constructors to throw an exception to prevent them from misusing the custom exception.

However, one cannot override Exception constructors.

Is there a way to disable them or get an equivalent behavior to prevent people from constructing my custom exception except how I want them to?

Answer (score 4):

The right way to fix this is to make your constructor private.  That should ensure that nobody can use it. For example:

```
public class MyCustomException extends Exception {
   private MyCustomException() {
     //Nah Nah Nah, now you can't construct me from outside anymore
   }
}
```

Comment: One caveat, though certainly an edge case, is that you could still deserialize an instance.

Comment: True. Though in the OP's use-case I suspect that will be harder than just using the right constructor.

Comment: Gave this a shot, but I still get:
-System exception constructor already defined: void <init>()-
It looks like making it private is still a version of overriding the Exception constructor. :(  Thanks though.